# Make ajax load linkable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need my ajax loads to be linkable, but I think the way it is programmed does not work in the usual way for me.
I saw this plugin, but I could not make it work: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

```
<a class="page2" href="#page2">Page 2</a>
```

And script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.page2').on('click', function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
            $('#ajax').css({
                display: 'block'
            }).animate({
                height: '0'
            }).empty();
        }
        $('#ajax').css({
            display: 'block'
        }).animate({
            height: '500px'
        }, function () {
            $('#loader').css({
                border: 'none',
                position: 'relative',
                top: '24px',
                left: '48px',
                boxShadow: 'none'
            });
            $('#ajax').load('page2.php ' + href, function () {
                $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why does it not work? What is going wrong? What are you expecting?

Comment: My programming skills are almost nonexistant. So copying the code like it says did not work at all. also my method of loading with ajax looks completely different. What is going wrong: I was able to change the url title, but not make the call linkable.

Comment: What errors do you get in your console.